# Does the average of the product of random variables that converge in probability to zero also converge to zero?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $Y_i$ have finite moments. $Y_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ if $i \neq j$

Suppose that $X_{i,N}$ converges in probability to zero, for any $i$, as N increases. $X_{i,N}$ and $X_{j,N}$ can be correlated when $ i \neq j $, but the correlation vanishes as N grows.

$Y_i$ and $X_{i,N}$ are not uncorrelated but become uncorrelated as N grows.

Is there any way to show that $ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N  X_{i,N} Y_i $ converges in probability to zero as N grows? Or do I need to assume more?

Is there any problem with writing $ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N  X_{i,N}  Y_i =  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N  o_p(1) Y_i =   o_p(1)  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N   Y_i $? Seems too simple.

Comment: What if $X_{i,N} = N \delta_{i,N}$ (deterministic), and the $Y_i$ are iid?

Comment: Then $X_{i,N}=o_p(1)$ implies $\delta_{i,N}=o_p (\frac{1}{N})$. The proposed solution still holds, no?

Comment: No, the notation $\delta_{i,j}$ is intended to be the Dirac delta, meaning $\delta_{i,j}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{i,j}=0$ otherwise.